# PS4 black ops 3 campaign - what do the different color boxes mean by mission name?

Tags: ps4, call-of-duty-black-ops-3

So, I've been playing through campaign on PS4 and one day when "resuming campaign"  it tried to make me replay the "Hypocenter" mission which I had finished earlier.  I quit out and went to the next mission "Vengeance" (which was unlocked). I have noticed now, in the mission select screen, that all the missions up to "Hypocenter" have a green box by the name, while the ones I've done after have a grey square with an X.  Any time now I try to restart mission the games thing I'm still at "Hypocenter".

Did I screw something up?  Anybody know exactly what these boxes mean?

Thank you

EDIT:  Just realized I have not been getting trophies for the missions since Hypocenter.

Comment: Can not confirm, so not going to answer. But all references I find online tell me that you should be able to play any of the single player levels, immediately. If that is the case, I would say that you have hypocenter registered as incomplete in your save.

Comment: Yea it is starting to look that way... wonder what I did to cause that!  Oh well, guess I just gotta bite the bullet and start back there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green square is for when you have completed by yourself in campaign mode. I just hit resume campaign knowing I had a box with an X in it on the mission it was starting me on and when I completed the mission it turned to a green box but of course I'm on Xbox one so hopefully it's the same for u on PS4

Answer (score 0):

It appears that black ops 3 allows you to access any level from the start.

It would seem that you have not registered completion of Hypocenter, but the proceeding levels should be unlocked, regardless.

Comment: I don't disagree with this answer, but can we find something a little more definitive about what the boxes next to the mission titles mean (green box, vs, grey box, etc.)  I'm sure we can guess correctly, but I'd like if we had something official.  (I'll certainly accept your answer then and delete this comment!).